Vite with react throw 404 error src/main.tsx
I am using vite and react. I have two problems. The first one is that vite-pwa plugin is installed on every single react project, even when I only start the project. I tried to uninstall it, but failed.
The second problem I encounter, is 404 imediatelly after I install the project...
This is the error in question:
GET http://localhost:5173/src/main.tsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:23 
        
 GET http://localhost:5173/@vite-plugin-pwa/pwa-entry-point-loaded net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
manifest.webmanifest:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

The first error is from Vite. I just installed the project, using no other dependency.
I don't know where to start looking for help..

I was getting the same error after upgrading the Node version, and I had to change the Vite port and explicitly specify localhost in vite.config.ts.
server: {
host: "127.0.0.1",
port: 3000,
},
